Prove that if $K \subseteq X$ is compact and $F \subseteq X$ is closed, then $K \cap F$ is compact
Let $(X,d)$ a metric space. Prove that if $K \subseteq X$ is compact and $F \subseteq X$ is closed, then $K \cap F$ is compact
Here's my proof so far, please check it.
Proof.
Assume that $K \subseteq X$ is compact and therefore sequentially compact such that there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$ with a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $x=lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k} \in K$ 
Also assume that $F \subseteq X$ is closed and therefore sequentially closed such that for every convergent sequence $(x_n)$ we have $x=lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \in F$ 
Since $x=lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k}=lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$, then $x \in K$ and $x \in F$ 
So $x=lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k}=lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \in K \cap F$. Every sequence and subsequence converges to a point $x \in K \cap F$, so $K \cap F$ is compact. $\blacksquare$
Not the best at writing proofs. If someone could clarify if I got something wrong and how to fix it that would be great. I tried not starting with the fact that there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K \cap F$ like my professor did, because I wouldnt have even thought to start like that in the first place.

The statement of the problem  does not say that you are in metric space.

I didn't write the entire problem, my bad. It's given that we are in metric space (X,d)

By the description of the tag solution-verification: "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

I think this proves that it is sequentially compact only. The proof is fairly easy if you prove that if $K\cap F$ is covered by some open sets, then there is a finite subcollection of those that also covers.

Where do you think you made a mistake ???

I’m voting to close this question because it does not meet the standards of the tag "solution-verification" for posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions.

You have generally the right idea, but the proof is not totally clear to me. In particular, I do not find it helpful to start out with a sequence of elements in $K$, since what you are really trying to do is show compactness of $K \cap F$.

Suppose $K$ is a compact subspace of $X$ and $F$ closed in $X$. Then $K \cap F$ is compact.

Note that $K \cap F$ is a metric space. Therefore, to show that it is compact, it suffices to show that it is sequentially compact. So, let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ be a sequence of elements in $K \cap F$. Since $K \supseteq K \cap F$ is a compact metric space, it is sequentially compact, so the sequence $(x_n)$ is guaranteed to have a convergent subsequence, say, $(x_{n_j})_{j \in \mathbb{Z}^+} \to x^* \in K$. Note that every element of the convergent sequence $(x_{n_j})$ - indeed, every element of $(x_n)$ - is contained in $F$. Since $(x_{n_j}) \to x^*$, then $x^* \in \text{Cl} \{ x_{n_j} \}_{j \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$. Since $\{ x_{n_j} \} \subseteq F$, then $\text{Cl} \{ x_{n_j} \} \subseteq \text{Cl} F = F$, showing that $x^* \in K \cap F$. Then $(x_{n_j})$ is a subsequence of $K \cap F$ that converges to $x^* \in K \cap F$, as desired.
Alternatively, observe that the set $K \cap F$, being the intersection of $K$ with a set $F$ that is closed in $X$, is closed in $K$ under the subspace topology. Then, just use that a closed subspace ($K \cap F$) of a compact space ($K$) is compact.

Let $K\cap F \subset \bigcup_{i \in I} U_{i}$ be an open cover. Since $F$ is closed, the complement $F^{\mathrm{c}}$ will be open and
\begin{equation*}
K \subset (K \cap F) \cup F^{\mathrm{c}} \subset \left(\bigcup_{i \in I} U_{i} \right) \cup F^{\mathrm{c}}
\end{equation*} will an open cover of $K$. Because $K$ is compact, you can choose a finit subcover $K \subset \left(\bigcup_{k = 1}^{m} U_{i_{k}} \right) \cup F^{\mathrm{c}}$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $F$ and $F^{\mathrm{c}}$ have no common elements, we get finally
\begin{equation}
K \cap F \subset \bigcup_{k = 1}^{m} U_{i_{k}}.
\end{equation}
